# Where to put 'dat' files need by JSP Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am developing a web application using jsp in Eclipse. 
I have put the java files needed by the jsp in a project and set the output folder, so it compiles successfully.

My project requires to read data from some dat files, I do not know where to keep them?

P.S. Those files are big ~500MB

Comment: external to application package, somewhere on file system (`~/app-name/data/`)

Answer (score 0):

For such big data file you should place it somewhere on file system rather storing it physically within web application.